# Shrink/expand size of child elements when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Im using [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/) for resizing of elements. The elements I want to resize have children within them however. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzkqe0yL/1/).

An element looks like this:

[image]

The layout within the image is controlled by flex. I then use the interact.js library to resize the element:

[image]

As you can see, the container element resizes but not the child elements.

The html is:

```
<div class="flex resize-container">
    <div class="resize-drag">

        <div class="aside-1">
                  menu stuff
        </div>

        <div class="graph-main ">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png" height="150" width="150" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.resize-drag {
    border: 1px gray dotted;
}
.aside-1 {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.graph-main {
    flex: 4;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And js:

```
interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    onmove: window.dragMoveListener
  })
  .resizable({
    preserveAspectRatio: true,
    edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
  })
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

  });
```

I would like the elements inside to shrink or expand, and hold their positions, as I resize. Is this possible? Or is there a better library?

**EDIT**

I tried Louis' suggestion but it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/jnk2tjea/

Answer (score 1):

Your image have a fixed with and height (150px here).
You should specify a relative size, which will be a porcentage of the parent's div. Add the following CSS code and delete the fixed size :

```css
.graph-main img {
    width : 100%;
}
```

Note that to work with porcentage, the parent div must have a fixed size.

Here is a [link to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/8mxckrdz/2/) with the fix.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in my code. I just posted an edit about it. Hope it will help